# Does parallel programming using CUDA and Matlab work per array basis or per function basis?

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I am pretty much a noob when it comes to using CUDA.

I was reading about CUDA and Matlab in the Nvidia website and the tutorial seems to be declaring GPUarray. I searched a lot but couldn't find a multithreaded function call there.

So I was wondering if it is allowed to make a function call per thread basis ?

Like

```
function f = something(some params),
..
..
..
end
```

can I call that function per thread? Just like how Java works ?

Comment: You can use [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-element-wise-matlab-code-on-a-gpu.html) to call a function on a per-element basis.  Using the [mex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mex-functions-containing-cuda-code.html) or [ptx interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html), there are many possibilities.  Certainly you could run a user defined function per *GPU thread* that way.